# Get the size of an image while parsing with the DOMDocument

Tags: php, image, parsing, getimagesize

I am parsing website (not any in particular but a variety) and saving various information from them including images. So far I am saving the image src and then going back through again to check the size of the image. What I would like to do is check the image size when I first parse the page....

Here's what I have...

```
    $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $imageArray = array();

    foreach ($imgs as $img) {
        $image = $this->returnProperURL($img->getAttribute('src'));
        $imageSize = getimagesize($image);
        $imageWidth = $imageSize[0];
        $imageHeight = $imageSize[1];

        if($imageWidth > $this->minImageWidth && $imageHeight > $this->minImageHeight){
            $imageArray[] = $image;
        }
    }
```

instead of using the getimagesize() after I have the image src is there a way I can check the image size the first time through when I am parsing it? As I'm sure you suspect, it's taking twice as long as it should.

Comment: You can only get the image size from the image. The HTML document won't have any reliable information that you can use.

Comment: I get that but I'm hoping there is some kind of way to keep my external queries down to a minimum. Reaching out to two urls for one image certainly isn't efficient.

Comment: You could cache each image `src` along with size somehow, then check to see if you'd already fetched that info before asking for it. How effective that would be would depend on the nature of your application.